# Laravel - Hierarchy in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, hierarchy, eloquent

my database have this hierarchy:

```
- Manager:
  - Coordinator:
    - Supervisor:
      - Operator
```

this code, output all "coordinator" belongs to "manager":

```
Manager::find(1)->coordinator()->get();
```

is possible get all "supervisor" belongs to "coordinator" directly? Example:

```
Manager::find(1)->coordinator()->supervisor()->get();
```

*Sorry by english, i'm brazilian*

Comment: Yes, that's possible you just need to define all the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly possible, you just need to define all the relationship in your models. Then you could retrieve all all your "operators" for a specific "manager" by doing:

```
Manager::find(1)->coordinator->supervisor->operator;
```

In that code, I'm using dynamic properites that come with Eloquent ORM.

When I said 'you need to defin all the relationships in your models' doing the following:

```
class Manager extends Eloquent
{
    public function coordinator()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Coordinator');
    }
}
```

Then you will do the same for coordinator that has many supervisors and for supervisor that has many operators.

See the documentation about [Relationship, one-to-many, in Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many).

Comment: I had done this way, but return this: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$supervisor

Comment: Remove the dollar sign.

Comment: Found 'error', was return a Collection -Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection - add ->first() or in loop and work!! Thanks